# How long google analytics' Unity Plugin take to generate report once custom-event(s) are setup? Unity Analytics takes 8-10 hours

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

I'm implementing analytics in my game to track a player's action, gameplay strategy etc.

I tried Unity Analytics and every time I set some custom event like a scene change I have to wait 8-10 hours to see the changes on Unity Dashboard.
If someone has used Google Analytics' Unity Plugin, can you share your experience?

Also, we are building a VR app using Unity that will run on a Windows machine. I didn't saw any configuration for Windows platform. Is there something like that exist?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics is a very powerful analytic tool, i highly recommend it. Usually it takes 5 seconds Google Analytics to update any event you send to the dashboard.

Comment: Does it support Windows' app? We are building a VR app that runs on a Windows machine.

Comment: I did not use on a Windows app so i do not want to miss lead you. However, Google Analytics gets event calls even from Unity's editor labeled as "Desktop" so i guess it should work but i'm not sure. :)

Comment: Ok Thanks, I will give it a try.